# Is it possible to make a weak analog low-pass filter with less than 20 dB/decade roll-off?

Tags: analog, filter

Part of Respawned Fluff's answer to [this recent question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200254/why-arent-active-headphones-equalized-to-a-flat-frequency-response) on headphones got me thinking about low-pass filters:

> It seems they actually invert the transfer function of the dummy head/ears via software because they say right before that that "Theoretically, this graph should be a flat line at 0dB."... but I'm not entirely sure what they do... because after that they say "A “natural sounding” headphone should be slightly higher in the bass (about 3 or 4 dB) between 40Hz and 500Hz." and "Headphones also need to be rolled-off in the highs to compensate for the drivers being so close to the ear; **a gently sloping flat line from 1kHz to about 8-10dB down at 20kHz is about right**." Which doesn't quite compile for me in relation to their previous statement about inverting/removing the HRTF.

This is talking about headphones, not circuits, but it made me wonder if it's possible to create such a transfer function with an analog circuit. First-order filters have a slope of -20 dB/decade. Is there anything weaker? I suppose the transfer function would be something like this:

$$H(s) = \frac 1 {1 + \sqrt{s / \omega_c}}$$

Comment: In RF, you could use the skin effect to get a \$1/\sqrt{f}\$ characteristic. I imagine at lower frequencies you could use a combination of discrete elements to form both poles and zeros to approximate that characteristic over some band. Or find a material (like in a ferrite bead, for example) with a convenient frequency dependence.

Comment: First order filters have a maximum slope of 20dB/decade. Now consider one with an R in series with the C (as in lag-lead compensation) - its ultimate slope is ... 0 again, and it may never reach 20dB/decade. A network of several of these at different frequencies can deliver a slope as shallow as you want.

Comment: I disagree that a headphone needs the bass boosted and the treble reduced.
Use the "cut" parts of a Baxandall treble tone control. Replace its pot with two resistors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is but it's more complex because you have to use breakpoints formed by a multiple array of resistors and capacitors:

[image]

The above is a piecemeal 3dB per octave (10 dB per decade) filter. It was designed to convert white noise to pink noise. See [this link](http://www.decodesystems.com/pink-noise.html).

[Here's](https://sound-au.com/project11.htm) another white to pink noise filter using an op-amp with a few more breakpoints:

[image]

You could convert it to 2 dB per octave or 4 dB per octave but the accuracy comes from the number of breakpoints and therefore the number of RCR stages.

Note that pink noise rolls off at 3 dB per octave and here's the final "circuit" and graph:

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey Andy, thanks for the circuits.  could you get a better photo of the first passive circuit or tell us what the resistor and capacitor values are.  the numbers are pretty badly smudged.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson quite smudged indeed, but kind of readable: top-left R: 6.3k, middle 3 Rs: 3k, 1k, 300, middle 4 Cs: 1uF, 270nF, 2x 47nF. the rightmost cap seems to be 33nF.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson this was the site I took the picture from: http://www.decodesystems.com/pink-noise.html  - the left resistor I reckon is 6k8 but it is the general principle that is important here. If you look at the 3rd circuit - it has values that are all 10x the first circuit.

Answer (score 2):

> ...it made me wonder if it's possible to create such a transfer function
>   with an analog circuit. First-order filters have a slope of -20 dB/decade. 
>   Is there anything weaker?

The answer is *yes*. The keyword to this is *fractional order filters* and there is some literature on this topic, although not much. These filters are based on fractional order elements, which are usually approximated with conventional, lumped-element circuits. Optimization techniques or Padé approximations may provide a close-enough implementation. Wikipedia has an [article on Fractional-order systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional-order_system) which may be a starting point to learn about these.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a series of five high-shelf filters spread evenly at octave spacings, each one contributing a cut of -2dB. The first would have a corner at 1kHz, the next at 2kHz, the next at 4kHz, the next at 8kHz, and the last at 16kHz. That would meet your spec pretty nicely, giving you a -2dB cut from 1-2kHz, a -4dB cut from 2-4kHz, a -6dB cut from 4-8kHz, a -8dB cut from 8-16kHz, and a -10dB cut above 16kHz.

(If you really HAD to have an even more gradual roll-off than that, you could even use 10 high-shelfs, at half-octave spacings and each contributing a cut of -1dB, but I really think that would be serious overkill.)